# Netplan persistency

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, netplan, systemd-networkd

I have a script that modified a lot of routes by using `ip route` and it also edits the netplan config in /etc/netplan. However I've noticed that when a ip link goes down temporarily and then up again it loses the routes and it does not load the data from the netplan config but rather uses some internal state that is to my knowledge only reloadable by either running `netplan apply` or `netplan generate` + `systemctl reload systemd-networkd.service`. However running those also causes small amount of network downtime. Is there any way to reload the internal state without causing downtime?

Running ubuntu 22.04 with netplan and systemd-networkd.